# Is there a way to add PHP code to a clickable link?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way to do some web site tracking for a business.  Is there a way to add PHP code to a clickable link on a web page so that when a user clicks on a link that will take them to a different page, the PHP code is executed right before the click action is taken?
So something like this would execute some PHP code before linking to the web site?
    [Stackoverflow link](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Do you have any control over where the links go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to a PHP function, run your code, last line of the function would be a header line.
    header(Location: 'http://whateverlink.com');

Really no different than submitting a PHP form

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly. PHP is for server-side code only. I would suggest that you look at a tool like Mixpanel, Kissmetrics, or Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side scripting language.  Thus, it cannot be run client-side in their browser as all processing must be done on the server itself.

You could use Javascript to attain the functionality you desire.

On your page, you could do something similar to:

```
<!-- In your page head -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myLinkFunction() {
        // Do some Javascript here to track the click
        // If you have jQuery on your page, you could do this:
        $.post("trackclick.php", { link-id: "212", other-info: "some data" } );
        // Send the user to the linked page:
        return true;
    }
</script>

<!-- Somewhere else -->
<a href="somepage.html" onClick="myLinkFunction();">Link</a>
```

Comment: Is it simple to run a MySQL insert from the javascript?  As I have a real simple PHP that inserts just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can link to a PHP page on your web site and use `header('Location: <new url>')` to redirect after you have executed your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

If you was using jQuery you could do something like:

```
<a href="link.html" class="link">liunk</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $url = $(this).attr('href');
        var logged = $.post('tracking-script.php', {link: $url});

        //  from 'tracking-script.php' return a string of yes or something

        if(logged == 'yes') {
            //window.location = $url;
            return true;    
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a tracking code or integer using $_GET. Then on the top of the next page before any HTML, you would run some small tracking code.  The tracking code could update a database or flat file, depending on your preference.

```
landingpage.html
 <a href = "somepage.php?tracking=1">Next Page</a>

somepage.php
 $tally = $_GET['tracking'];
 $track = $tally." from landingpage.html";
 $handle = fopen('path/to/tracks.txt','a');
 fwrite($handle, $track);
```

This is way simplified, but the process is (a)ppending a string on to the end of a text file called tracks.txt.  You could process tracks.txt in other ways, like tallying the numbers of links from some given page.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what people say you can do this, in combination with javascript.
this is a method you have no doubt heard of called "AJAX". what this means is you run a Javascript function that calls a PHP script in the background.

w3schools have a great tutorial on it: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

you can use both POST & GET Methods to pass the data to a php function. 
it will be something like this:

```
function showHint(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
 if (str.length==0)
 { 
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
 return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

so in essence the "str" string is the value you wish to pass into the javascript function and then to the PHP file via a get method shown here  xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.asp?q="+str,true); this could just as easily be  xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true); PHP or ASP it makes little difference. the next thing to remember is the "txtHint" is a HTML element which you wish the response from the page to return into. so for example you could have the "gethint.php" or asp to echo "Success" or "Fail".

on a side note if you wish you style the responses this can be done through the same style sheet as the rest of your page. I hope this helps mate :)